# Django - How do I get display name inside queryset .values()

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've got the following manager:

```
class Totals(Manager):

def by_customer_and_date(self, start_date, end_date):

    qs = self.model.objects.filter(
        date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).values(
        "customer"
    ).annotate(
        ...bunch of stuff...
    )

    return qs
```

Where `customer` is a FK relation to another object. Right now, the queryset packs in the related `customer` objects' ids, but I'd like it to use the display names instead so I can pack it up all nicely for my template.

For now, I've added the following into the manger:

```
for q in qs:
    q['customer'] = Customer.objects.get(id=q.get('customer')).name
```

It works fine, but it feels like extra work.. for me it's 50 database hits as opposed to one. Are there any shortcuts to putting the display name in the qs dictionary right off the bat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get to related object fields by using `__`.

```
qs = self.model.objects.filter(
    date__range=(start_date, end_date)
).values(
    "customer__name"
)
```

Comment: Right on. I love Django. Now I can grab it in my template with `{{ item.customer__name }}`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `__` within your values like this `.values("customer__name")` to select field on related table.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get all related customer names.

```
class Totals(Manager):

def by_customer_and_date(self, start_date, end_date):

    name_list = self.model.objects.filter(
        date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).values("customer__name", flat=True)

    return name_list
```